# Differing browser window height for one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have some simple JavaScript to set the height of all displayed pictures on a page to the height of the browser window minus some pixels:

```
$("img").each( function() {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    console.log(window_height)
    $(this).height(window_height - 100)
});
```

The first image always has a class of `active` whereas the remaining ones have `hidden`. These CSS rules are defined for these classes:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Now, when I load the page that contains four images of various sizes (in original), and the first image is active, it outputs the following to the console log:

```
552
565
565
565
```

However, if I have the second image as active and the first and all other ones hidden, it outputs the same height for all four.

Why would the size be different for the first image and the same for the rest in that particular order? I keep scratching my head around this one but can't figure it out.

Edit:

HTML:

```
<img src="./IMG_20141011_132657.jpg" class="active" />
<img src="./IMG_20141011_093916.jpg" class="hidden" />
<img src="./IMG_20141011_094009.jpg" class="hidden" />
<img src="./IMG_20141011_100850.jpg" class="hidden" />
```

Comment: Is output same if you write style="height:100%" in <html> and <body> tag

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but in in this fiddle seems that everything working fine http://jsfiddle.net/k15rLmu3/

Comment: Please add your html as well

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please provide us with the HTML and the images you're using so that we can give you an accurate response. Thanks

Comment: Added the HTML, though it was described in the second paragraph.

Comment: Maybe Its connected with appearing scrollbar on the bottom of website when you will add image? Try to use `$(window).outerHeight()` instead `.height()`

Comment: @Wado, nope, same result :( It's odd that your jsfiddle works as expected but my code which is pretty much the same does not. Very weird.

Comment: could you `consol.log()` those values: `$(window).height()` then asign it to IMG and consol.log `$(this).height()` and check do both values will be the same?

Comment: @Wado, does the same: http://fpaste.org/144881/14141609/

Comment: @mart1n So only one possibility is that after you resize first image it affect window height somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63591/discussion-between-mart1n-and-wado).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the first image is wider than body width, thus creating a horizontal scroll-bar making window height smaller. After resizing the first image, the image is no longer wider than body width and the horizontal scrollbar is no more.

The JavaScript `window.innerHeight` will not take scrollbar into account, try this:

```
$("img").each( function() {
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    console.log(window_height)
    $(this).height(window_height - 100)
});
```